# Doing flatmap on a function returning RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to process multiple avro files in the code below. the idea is to first get a series of avro files in a list. then open each avro file and generate a steam of tuples (string, int). then finally group the stream of tuples by key and sum the ints.

```
object AvroCopyUtil {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Leads Data Analysis").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    val avroList = GetAvroList(fs, args(0))
    avroList.flatMap(av =>
      sc.newAPIHadoopFile[AvroKey[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]](av)
        .map(r => (r._1.datum.get("field").toString, 1)))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      .foreach(println)
  }


  def GetAvroList(fs: FileSystem, input: String) : List[String] = {
    // get all children
    val masterList : List[FileStatus] = fs.listStatus(new Path(input)).toList
    val (allFiles, allDirs) = masterList.partition(x => x.isDirectory == false)
    allFiles.map(_.getPath.toString) ::: allDirs.map(_.getPath.toString).flatMap(x => GetAvroList(fs, x))
  }
}
```

The compile error i get is

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey[org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord], org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable)]
[error]  required: TraversableOnce[?]
[error]     avroRdd.flatMap(av => sc.newAPIHadoopFile[AvroKey[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]](av))
[error]                                                                                                                       ^
[error] one error found
```

Edit: based on the suggestion below I tried

```
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[AvroKey[GenericRecord], NullWritable, 
AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]](avroList.mkString(","))
```

but I got the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 2015-10-
15-00-1576041136-flumetracker.foo.com-FooAvroEvent.1444867200044.avro,hdfs:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is unnecessary. You are also attempting to create an RDD within a transformation which doesn't really make sense. The transformation (in this case, `flatMap`) runs on top of an RDD and the records within an RDD will be what is transformed. In the case of a `flatMap`, the expected output of the anonymous function is a `TraversableOnce` object which will then be flattened into multiple records by the transformation. Looking at your code though, you don't really need to do a `flatMap` as a simply `map` will suffice. Keep in mind also that due to the immutability of RDD's, you must always reassign your transformations into new values.

Try something like:

```
val avroRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[AvroKey[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]](filePath)
val countsRDD = avroRDD.map(av => (av._1.datum.get("field1").toString, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

It seems as though you may need to take some time to grasp some of Spark's basic framework nuances. I would recommend fully reading the [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html). Lastly, if you want to use Avro, please also check out [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) as much of the boiler plate around working with Avro is taken care of there (and DataFrames may perhaps be more intuitive and easier to use for your use case).

(EDIT:)

It seems like you may have misunderstood how to load data to be processed in Spark. The `parallelize()` method is used to distribute collections across an RDD and not data within files. To do the latter, you actually only need to provide a comma-separated list of input files to the `newAPIHadoopFile()` loader. So assuming your `GetAvroList()` function works, you can do:

```
val avroList = GetAvroList(fs, args(0))
val avroRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[AvroKey[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]](avroList.mkString(","))
val countsRDD = avroRDD.map(av => (av._1.datum.get("field1").toString, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
flatMappedRDD.foreach(println)
```

Comment: actually, I am processing multiple avro files. let me post the full code so that it makes sense.

Comment: each avro files generates a RDD[(String, Int)] the flatmap is used to have a single RDD[(String, Int)] from all avro files.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Updated, let me know if that helps!

Comment: still not working. it says there is a problem with the scheme name

Comment: Weird, can you print the output of `GetAvroList()` in your example run? The function `newAPIHadoopFile()` should be able to [take multiple files as input from 1.3.1 onwards](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7155).